# Xamarin Compile From windows to Mac compatibility

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

i've on my pc windows i've install visual studio 2015 I want to say if is possibile to compile my xamarin project on ios with Visual Studio 2017 for mac? I check from visual studio site but only version of visual studio for mac is 2017.
Thanks any help is apprecied

Comment: You need to describe more about your "Xamarin project". Most should work but some (UWP related) won't.

Comment: Project is very simple same hello world i'm a newbie, i make a simple project on android but i want to compile on mac. I need to install on mac visual studio for build ios project but the versions of two visual studio are diffefent in mac 2017 and on windows 2015 and i dont know if visual studio are compatible for build project. Thanks

Comment: I can only say "try it". Literally Visual Studio for Mac contains the same Xamarin bits like Visual Studio 2015, so everything should just work.

Comment: Ok i try it, but if not possible download visual studio 2015 for mac?

Comment: There is never Visual Studio 2015 for Mac.

Comment: @fraric `MSBuild` is the "same" on Windows and macOS, excluding C# language additions in newer versions of Roselyn, if the Xamarin.Android solution/project does not build on macOS, that would be a bug.

Comment: @fraric Yes. Your Xamarin form project from windows VS 2015 can be loaded and compiled on Mac VS 2017 but if it has UWP project in it, UWP part will not be loaded. You can only work on IOS and Android projects when migrating from Windows to Mac